# What is a stable version of animations for Angular 4?

Tags: angular, animation, npm-install

I get this error on npm install

**npm WARN @angular/animations@4.3.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.3.2 but none was installed.**

and I get this on npm start

**node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts(8,119): error TS2305: Module '"E:/Angular/quickstart-master1/quickstart-master/node_modules/@angular/animations/browser"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAnimationEngine'.**

this is what i get for ng -v

```
Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.2.1
node: 6.11.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.2
@angular/common: 4.0.3
@angular/compiler: 4.0.3
@angular/core: 4.0.3
@angular/forms: 4.0.3
@angular/http: 4.0.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.3
@angular/router: 4.0.3
```

Comment: You're trying to run the 4.3.2 version of Angular Animations and the 4.0.3 version of the rest of Angular. You should be running the same version across the board.

Comment: Hi @Hanan Ur Rehman, Can you please tell me the stable versions for angular libraries like @angular/animation, @angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/compiler and @angular/router for angular7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the packages below `@angular` should have the exact same version.

In your case, either use `@angular/animations@4.0.3` or, preferred, update the rest of the `@angular` package to `@latest`.

Comment: Hi @Hendrik Brummermann, where can I see the Stable versions for angular libraries?? Please help me out.. :)